# How to call a method of another ViewController from Appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

From my appdelegate I need to execute a method that is from a viewcontroller.

Please, can anybody tell me how to easily have the possibility to call whatever method I need from my appdelegate?

A lot of questions regarding this argument but none of these are useful/complete/right, so please avoid to post URL to other topics: I already checked all questions but I really can't find any precise answer regarding doing this in Swift. :)

Comment: You need a reference to the view controller in your app delegate. Then just call the method? theViewController.<method>....!

Comment: You only need to get a pointer to the controller whose method you want to call. Conceptually, this is a simple problem, but there's no way to give you a "precise" answer without knowing specifically what controller you're trying to access, and how it fits into your controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how you've arranged your view controllers but here's an example from a simple iPhone master/detail project.

```
let root : UINavigationController = self.window!.rootViewController! as UINavigationController
let master : MasterViewController = root.topViewController as MasterViewController
println("\(master.description)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to search for the view controller I want, starting on AppDelegate's `var window: UIWindow?` and then going deeper until I find it. I originally tried to implement `NSNotification` but this is not recommended on swift (I think computed property is a good replace for that, but it don't work in this case).

This is how I did for my tab based application with a NavigationController on top of my ViewController:

```
if let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    if let viewControllers = rootViewController.viewControllers {
        for navigationController in viewControllers {
            if let yourViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? YourCustomViewController {
                if yourViewController.hasSomeFlag {
                    yourViewController.theMethod()
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with notifications, just add observer to your viewcontroller, post a notification from your app delegate, this observer will catch it and run a function you specify.

this tutorial should help get you started: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-implement-an-nsnotification-observer-in-swift

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return true
}

func customMethod()
{

}
}
```

Call custom method from ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    appDelegate.customMethod()
}
```